# Can a math software do decide whether an abstract simplicial complex is or not a matroid?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, math-software, simplicial-complex, matroids

As the title suggests, I need to know if there exists some math software deciding whether an abstract simplicial complex is or not a matroid. In other terms, I would like to give a finite ground set and an abstract simplicial complex on it as input and to obtain as output true if the given abstract simplicial complex is the family of the independent sets of a matroid, false otherwise.

I tried to google a few, but I have not found nothing on such a problem. I fear that some computational obstruction is preventing the implementation of this algorithm. Otherwise, it seems strange to me that no specialized software points out such a functionality. Can you please help me? It is really important for me to have my question answered.

Comment: "is a matroid" in what sense?  the independent sets of a matroid?

Comment: Yes, the family of the independent sets of a matroid

Comment: Have you tried using Sage's matroid constructor, followed by the M.is_valid() function?  See https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matroids/sage/matroids/constructor.html

Comment: I'll try it. Are there other programs doing it?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry; maybe someone else will.

Comment: @JBL  Thank you for your kind reply!

Comment: I did something similar a decade ago using Maple, and it was not too complicated. Unfortunately, I lost the source code (and it would not be optimized anyway). An abstract simplicial complex is a set of sets so the data representation is relatively simple and the "basis exchange property" of matroid translates quite well (loops) into algorithms and can probably be implemented in any language.